# Using "display: inline-block" in my container CSS aligns it on the left, how to get container at center of page?

Tags: html, css

I have tried using align:center but it is not working. How can i get the container at the center of page ?

Comment: Can you include your HTML / CSS? Also, it would be `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/x5bceLvt/

add `text-align:center` to parent

```css
    .cont {
      text-align: center
    }
    .inline {
      display: inline-block;
      background: grey;
    }
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="inline">hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<div id="container">
    demo
</div>
```

In CSS :

```
#container
{
   margin:0 auto;
   width:100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Demo in FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yamodL7g/1/)